# Visually distinguish AWS accounts (prod vs dev)

Tags: amazon-web-services

Is there a way to visually distinguish AWS accounts? Something like adding a banner on the top of AWS console with the word "prod" on it? we have several accounts for different environments and it is really easy to get confused. Any ideas/best practices?